# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException in Winrt Package

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am developing an app in **Windows 8 (XAML)**.

The application runs fine on local machine, however when I create a package in **Release Mode** and test the app, it crashes.

I saw the application log in my computer and found this error

> Application: MyApp.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   Stack:
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext+Invoker.b__0(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>      at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Comment: You should probably share some relevant source code for context.

Comment: Which Part of the code??

Comment: Crashes all the places :( and quite frquently

Comment: Sounds like you have faulty hardware or OS. I would start with reinstall of windows 8. Is this within a virtual or physical Win8 machine?

Comment: Physical Win8 Machine..How is it working in developing environment(i.e Visual Studio)

Comment: Gotcha - so **Debug** works - just not **Release** mode.

Comment: Are you using Windows 8 RTM or RP? Does an empty app do it or only your specific app? If it is only yours - you could try to enable breaking on all exceptions, enable unmanaged code debugging and enable getting the debugging symbols from Microsoft to see if you could get more details. Otherwise - you could try to remove pieced of your app one by one to see which specific one is causing the problem.